# Failed to load resource: status 404

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to specify the path to the CSS and JS files. But all the time I get same error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>   I'm just studying programming. Could you help handle it?
>   https://prnt.sc/ntrhw2
>   https://prnt.sc/ntri11

i've tried all options that I could find:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/style.css">
```

I'm using Tomcat 9.0.16 + Thymeleaf + Java.

The most interesting part - when I run HTML page from desktop - all works fine. But when I start Tomcat - not.

I already tried all options I found on whole internet, including this:

```
<link type="text/css" th:src="@{//static/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet">
<script>th:src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css"> </script>

<link type="text/css" th:href="@{//static/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" scr:="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But is still doesn't work. Could somebody explain me where mistake is? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Add context path to your resource path `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

Comment: make sure you file path is correct

Comment: Path is correct: https://prnt.sc/ntrplx but it's not working on Tomcat.
How exactly I have to add context path to resource path?

Comment: Do what Shubh told this will work.